# Bash function, export function argument as environment variable

Tags: bash, export, environment-variables

I wrote a bash function to export an environment variable. First function argument is a variable name, second is a variable value. I want to `echo` it to show what value was exported:

```
#!/bin/bash

env_var_export()
{
    export $1=$2

echo ""
echo "  export $1=$$1"
echo ""
}

env_var_export var defaultVal456
```

I mean, echo should print: `export var=defaultVal456`. Any help? I know I can do this:

```
echo ""
echo "  export $1=$2"
echo ""
```

but its not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$` is a special variable that expands to the shell's pid, and that's what is going to be evaluated in your `echo`. You should instead use an indirect reference like this:

```
echo ""
echo "  export $1=${!1}"
echo ""
```

This syntax will take the variable named in `$1` and then lookup the value based on that name (i.e. indirection).

Comment: Took me forever to find this reply! Thank you for making this answer 3 years ago.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)